# How can I place a widget at the very bottom of a tkinter window when positioning with .grid()?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am aware that you cannot use different types of geometry managers within the same Tkinter window, such as .grid() and .pack(). I have a window that has been laid out using .grid() and I am now trying to add a status bar that would be snapped to the bottom of the window. The only method I have found online for this is to use .pack(side = BOTTOM), which will not work since the rest of the window uses .grid().

Is there a way that I can select the bottom of the window to place widgets from when using .grid()?

Comment: Provide ome example code of what you want to achieve

Comment: You could do your status bar pack in the first level, with the other windows inside another window that is packed as well. 

root->(statusbar (pack), other(pack))
other(pack)-> (window1(grid),window2(grid))

I'll post full code if you need it.

Comment: The best suggestion would be like @Jason Chia commented. Since i started with tkinter i always had the same issue. The best think you can do is to split your main window into __frames__. Manage your main window with grid method. And then inside your frame ( the one in bottom ) create your status bar. Since this frame is empty yet from widgets, you can add a status bar there with pack and use side=BOTTOM

Comment: ***"at the very bottom of a tkinter window when positioning with .grid()?"***: Use `.grid_rowconfigure(<row index of bottom widget -1>, weight=1)`. This forces the LayoutManager to size the space before the bottom widget as large as possible.

Comment: @JimErginbash Missed the keyword frames :D

Comment: @JasonChia to be honest I am very new to Tkinter and struggling to visualise what you mean, so it would be helpful if you could post the full code if possible!

Answer (score 3):

Just give it a `row` argument that is larger than any other row. Then, give a weight to at least one of the rows before it.

Even better is to use frames to organize your code. Pack the scrollbar on the bottom and a frame above it. Then, use grid for everything inside the frame.

Example:

```
# layout of the root window
main = tk.Frame(root)
statusbar = tk.Label(root, text="this is the statusbar", anchor="w")

statusbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

# layout of the main window
for row in range(1, 10):
    label = tk.Label(main, text=f"R{row}")
    label.grid(row=row, sticky="nsew")
    main.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter as tk

class sample(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.status = StringVar()
        self.status.set("Initializing")
        statusbar = Label(root,textvariable = self.status,relief = SUNKEN, anchor = W)
        statusbar.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = X)
        self.parent1 = Frame()
        self.parent1.pack(side = TOP) 
        self.createwidgets()
    def createwidgets(self):
        Label(self.parent1,text = "Grid 1,1").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        Label(self.parent1,text = "Grid 1,2").grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        Label(self.parent1,text = "Grid 2,1").grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        Label(self.parent1,text = "Grid 2,2").grid(row = 2, column = 2)




if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    app = sample(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

So using labels since I was kinda lazy to do other stuff, you can do frames to ensure that each section of your window can be packed/grid as required. Frames will be a useful tool for you to use when trying to arrange your widgets. Note that using a class can make things a little easier when deciding your parents. So imagine each frame is a parent and their children can be packed as required. So I would recommend drawing out your desired GUI and see how you will arrange them. Also if you want to add another frame within a frame simply do:

```
self.level2 = Frame(self.parent1)
```

You can check out additional settings in the docs

> http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm

PS: I am using a class hence the self, if you don't want to use classes then its okay to just change it to be without a class. Classes make it nicer to read though